# For Loop doesn't space characters properly

Tags: java, for-loop, netbeans-8

I'm trying to make a program which spaces the < and > characters equal to the number of spaces in the variable start, + 3.

I've tried removing the parentheses and switching things around, but regardless the two characters are still being printed next to each other. ("<>")

```
    System.out.print(" What size of spacing would you like? ");
    start = size + 1
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("<");
    for(int i = 0;i>(start+3);i++)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print(">");
```

I expected the output to be:

"<[number of spaces for start + 3]>" but instead it is "<>"

Comment: Your [`for` loop](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-for-loop) condition is the wrong way around. You want `i < (start + 3)`

Answer (score 0):

You might consider change your for loop to

```
for(int i = 0;i<(start+3);i++)
  {
    System.out.print(" ");
  }
```

Your code never enters the for loop as the condition is never met

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
System.out.println("<>".replaceAll("(?!^)([<>])", "   $1"));
```

this space you put between "   $1" is the amount of spaces you want to put between <>

Comment: I'm confused what this is doing. What do each of the characters in the quotes mean? Why is there a "$1" at the end?